# Loading from string instead of document/url

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I just found out about html agility pack and I tried it, but stumbled upon a problem. I couldn't find anything on the web so I am trying here.

Do you know how I can load the HTML from a string instead of document/URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Have you tried using **LoadHtml**?

```
string htmlString = 'Your html string here...';

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlString);

// Do whatever with htmlDocument here
```

Answer (score 3):

i think there's a function to do that right?

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("<test>");
```

Answer (score -1):

This post might be bit old. I think it will help others.

```
        WebBrowser web_browser = new WebBrowser();
        web_browser.DocumentText = html_contents_as_string;

        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while (web_browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
```